# solve for function which is the written in terms of itself and its inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, functions, real-numbers, inverse-function

Let, $f:\rm I\!R \rightarrow \rm I\!R$ be some function that is equal to a linear combination of itself and its inverse. Is is possible write an **explicit formula** for $f(x)$?
$$
f(x) = af(x) + bf^{-1}(x) \\
$$
$$
a \ne 0,1 \\
b \ne 0,1 
$$
Solve for $f(x)$.

Thank you for all your responses. Based on your comments, I am adding some restrictions on a and b

Comment: Letting $x=f(y)$, your condition implies $f(f(y)) = by/(1-a)$. Certainly there are many wild solutions to such a functional equation. This seems hopeless in the level of generality you're asking.

Comment: When $b=0$ and $a=1$ this equation holds for any bijective function $f$.

Comment: It seems like it can always be rewritten as $f(x) = c f^{-1}(x)$, where $c=\frac{b}{1-a}$, so we’re asking what functions are nonzero multiples of their inverses. One simple function would be $f(x)=\sqrt{c}x$, $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}x$.